# What is the purpose of "~/.adobe" directory?

Tags: mac, unix, adobe

I was cleaning my home directory and found hidden .adobe folder with two files in it:

```
md5 containing only one line "F894CEFB…"
userid containing also one line "424E8…"
```

I deleted whole folder and whole Adobe Creative Suite seems to work. Does anybody know what are these files for? Where does userid comes from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This answer](http://it.slashdot.org/comments.pl?sid=3446811&cid=42842417) in a discussion on [Slashdot](http://slashdot.org/) suggests this folder is not related to your Creative Suite installation, but to [Adobe Flash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_flash). I have it too, and the files in it are two years old. A candidate for deletion!